# Which TOS episode is that gif of Spock turning around and raising eyebrow from?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, episode-identification, spock

I'm looking for a *Star Trek* (the original series) clip where Spock slowly turns around and raises an eyebrow like in the below gif:

[image: Spock raising an eyebrow]

Or [this one](https://tenor.com/view/star-trek-spock-leonard-nimoy-raise-eyebrow-serious-gif-3842549).

Could anyone help me find the episode of this or a comparable scene?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is from *[TOS: Court Martial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Court_Martial_(Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series))*, timestamp 29:44.

Spock's actual line is

> *["chess?"](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/6959ca69-73ef-4ee2-8121-11b97c435bcd)*

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much!